# Resource request: Superfluid helium

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, flow, superfluidity, cold-atoms

I am wondering if anybody could recommend any good textbooks on the subject. So far, I have discovered (but not yet had a chance to read), a chapter in Landau-Lifshitz fluid mechanics (love Landau-Lifshitz!), as well as Introduction to Superfluidity: Field-theoretical Approach and Applications, by Andreas Schmitt.

We will primarily be looking at vorticity and flow, the fountain effect, as well as irrotational surface waves.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best match I could advise is

> Superconductivity, Superfluids and Condensates (Oxford Master Series
>   in Physics)

by James F Annett.

The level is for final year of a Physics bachelor's degree.

It covers Bose-Einstein condensation and superfluidity, along with superconductivity as well.

I would recommend it as a starting point.

Landau and Lifshitz, while extraordinary, are not ideal as a beginner's material. You should go back to them once you understand the basics, to see the whole thing in a more elegant, rigourous and probably detailed way.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had thought that this post was long dead...